# Are the reals $\mathbb{R}$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Are the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

$$\mathbb{R} \subset {\mathbb{R^2}}$$

Where $\mathbb{R}^2$ is defined as $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ whose elements are of the form $(x,y)$ where the notation $(.)$ denotes a pair and not an open interval and $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hint: can $1$ be found in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Not to confuse, but in the context of $\mathbb{C}$ the reals are often considered to be a subset  by identifying the real $x$ with $x+0i$.

Comment: Is $A$ a subset of $A\times B$? Strictly speaking, no. However, if both $A$ and $B$ are vector spaces over the same field, $A$ is a subspace of $A\times B$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, $\mathbb R$ is not a subset of $\mathbb R^2$, because, put simply, their elements are not of the same type. Since $\mathbb R$ consists of numbers and $\mathbb R^2$ consists of ordered pairs,
$$\mathbb R\cap\mathbb R^2=\varnothing$$
However, if $A\subset \mathbb R$, then
$$\mathbb R\times A\subset \mathbb R^2$$
and
$$A\times\mathbb R\subset \mathbb R^2$$

Answer (score 7):

No the real numbers are not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

In some contexts it may be useful to identify the real number $x$ with, for example, the couple $(x,0)$. (But you see there is no actual reason why $(x,0)$ rather than $(0,x)$ or maybe $(x,x)$.) Thus, this would need to be mentioned.

Comment: Doesn't this sort of depend on how the reals are constructed? It isn't immediately obvious to me that $x=\{y,\{x,y\}\}$ is impossible for some $x,y\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Yes by foundations it is prevented.  x in {x,y} in x.

Comment: @JorgeFernández I see what you mean but I do not consider this angle as the most appropriate way to approach this question. There is a difference between the conceptual notion of pairs of real numbers and *one* of its set-theoretical realizations. I took this question to be about the former. In the same way, I do not usually consider $17$ to be an element of $18$, while in some sense it can be considered as true.